# Scaling governor config not available on machine

Tags: linux, configuration, driver, cpu

I got a linux server with Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4110 CPU @ 2.10GHz process which is up to 3.00Ghz due to Intel Turbo Boost technology.

However, when im checking cpuinfo it says that are cores are working on 2095.078Mhz like always.

There are no up's and down's - no matter what (heavy process on server etc).
(im checking it by running cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz")

For example my laptop shows different MHz for every command run.

There is also no scaling_governor setting (i wanted to set performance mode).

Running cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor tells that cpufreq folder doesnt exists at all.

Im just curious if my processor is hitting these 3.0 Turbo cuz i dont feel like it does.
I feel like im lacking some kind of drivers for frequency scaling.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577401/there-is-no-scaling-max-freq-sys-file) is your answer.  If you can get the cpufreq driver loaded, you can consult the kernel docs to experiment and get the performance you want: [kernel.org cpufreq doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/cpufreq.html).

Comment: Hi, please don't add text asking for acceptance and salutations to your answers since remarks like that don't belong in answers. Asking for acceptance marks is also frowned upon and can lead to downvotes. Thanks!